# How to remove previous version of centos7 and install fresh centos7 in Toshiba Satellite using bootable USB

Tags: linux, centos

My centos 7 has been corrupted. I want to install fresh centos7. When I run `rpm -q kernel`. It gives the following results

```
kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64
```

I try to install from the boot-able pendrive and change the boot order starting from USB. But It is giving Message remove removable device and press any key to start.

**Please tell me how to install fresh centos 7 from USB and remove previous centos.**

Comment: Define "corrupted"? Is that `rpm -q` output the "corruption"? How did you create the usb image? Is it bootable?

Comment: @Etan Reisner, during the starting It gives error, and takes 30 min to give login windows please see this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201713/error-uncleared-pch-fifo-underrun-on-transcoder-a-during-boot-centos-7-on-tosh

Comment: Those appear to just be warnings. Do all the installed kernels in that list display them? Do they all take that long to boot?

Comment: It is probable that the message `Remove removable device and press any key to start` is coming from BIOS.

Comment: Are you booting to a Window Manager or a terminal console? It's possible that loading the window manager is taking a long time but not necessarily caused by corruption.

Answer (score 0):

rpm -q = query and its output is a result search.

for bootable disk, follow it:

1.Plug in your USB device to your Linux computer’s USB port.
2. Verify the device path of your USB storage with dmesg.
3. Proceed to (carefully!) image the ISO file on the USB device:

dd if=yourimage.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k

=)

I hope have helped you!! Sorry a little english